# Azure + Terraform and Multiple Bastion Instances

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Wondering, if it is possible to setup mulitple Bastion servers  + availability set on Azure using Terraform. I want to enumerate bastion nodes within given availability set, but do not want to use load balancer. Any examples, one could share?

Thanks!!

Comment: it is probably possible, however stack overflow is not a code writing service. what have you tried, what doesnt work?

Comment: Your question is off-topic. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question:

Yes it is possible to have multiple bastion nodes with Public IP addresses.

Sample configuration:

**File: nic.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "bastion_nic" {   name           
= "bastionnic${count.index + 1}"   location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"   resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"   network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.broker_nsg.id}"   count             
= "${var.bastion_instance_count}"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "bastionip${count.index + 1}"
    subnet_id                     = "${azurerm_subnet.broker_subnet.id}"
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id          = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.bastion_pip.*.id, count.index + 1)}"    } }
```

**File: ip.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "bastion_pip" {
  name                         = "bastionpip${ count.index + 1}"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  public_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
  domain_name_label            = "${var.kafka_cluster_prefix}-bastion${ count.index + 1}"
  count                          = "${var.bastion_instance_count}"
}
```

**File: bastion.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "bastion" {
  name                             = "bastion${count.index + 1}"
  count                            = "${var.bastion_instance_count}"
  location                         = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
  availability_set_id              = "${azurerm_availability_set.bastion.id}"
  resource_group_name              = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  network_interface_ids            = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.bastion_nic.*.id, count.index + 1)}"]
  vm_size                          = "${var.bastion_vm_size}"
  delete_os_disk_on_termination    = true
  delete_data_disks_on_termination = true
}
```

**File: availability.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_availability_set" "bastion" {
  name                = "bastionavailabilityset"
  managed             = "true"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg.location}"
}
```

If you follow the example, you will able to deploy multiple bastion nodes with public IP address in availability set. You need to define the following:

variable "`bastion_instance_count`" in your **variables.tf**

Cheers. Ping me if you need help.